# Java Arraylist loses methods/fields on get()

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, illegalaccessexception

I have a custom class called Trip that has a couple of getter methods, everything public.
I add several Trip objects to a ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<Trip> routeIndex;
```

When calling back one of these Trip objects with the following code, I incur a access error.

```
    Trip abc = routeIndex.get(0);
    for (Field field : abc.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String name = field.getName();
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(abc);
        System.out.printf("Field name: %s, Field value: %s%n", name, value);
    }
```

This is the following error on the Object value line:

```
unreported exception java.lang.IllegalAccessException; must be caught or declared when thrown
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Comment: This is called *checked exception*. You must wrap a `try/catch` block around those calls.

Comment: Also, you may declare `throws` on the function in order to allow the application to compile without changing its behaviour.

Comment: How does "I'm getting a compiler error" translate to the "Java Arraylist loses methods/fields on get()" of your title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `try/catch` block around `filed.get(abc)` cause the method `filed.get(Object obj)` would throw `IllegalAccessException` and you should handle with it.

So you just need change the `Object value = field.get(abc);` to

```
Object value = null;
try {
    value = field.get(abc);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and it works fine.